# How to wrap image with text?

Tags: wpf, image, text, textblock

How can I wrap a picture with a text which is binded like below.
and if I try that below I will have the error:

> Error 1 A value of type 'TextBlock' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'BlockCollection'

```
            <FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
                <FlowDocument IsHyphenationEnabled="True" IsOptimalParagraphEnabled="True" LineHeight="10" LineStackingStrategy="MaxHeight" TextAlignment="Left">
                    <Paragraph>

                        <Floater Width="130" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,5,5" Padding="3">
                            <TextBlock Margin="5" TextAlignment="center" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                               Text="{Binding Path=TitleTip}" FontSize="12" Name="style"> </TextBlock>
                            <BlockUIContainer >
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=Picture}" Margin="5" Height="30"></Image>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </BlockUIContainer>
                        </Floater>
                    </Paragraph>
                    <Paragraph></Paragraph>
                </FlowDocument>
            </FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to surround TextBlock with BlockUIContainer or include it in the existing BlockUIContainer

```
<BlockUIContainer > 
<TextBlock Margin="5" TextAlignment="center" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
 Text="{Binding Path=TitleTip}" FontSize="12" Name="style"> </TextBlock>
 </BlockUIContainer >
```